# how to generate delay on xilinx spartan 6 board?

Tags: delay, verilog

I am learning Verilog HDL. And now, I am trying to run a program on Digilent Atlys Spartan 6 xc6slx45.
I am implementing this counter on the board.

```
module counter_s2( output reg [7:0] count);

initial begin
  count=0;
  repeat(127) begin
    #10000000 count=count+1;
  end
end

endmodule
```

When I run this code on the board, I get final input of 1111111. There is no delay coming on the board. I want to produce a delay of, lets say 1 second, to see the output.
Thanks!

P.S: I am new to Verilog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have created is fine for a testbench component and will work in simulation, but certain parts of it are not synthesisable.

In particular `initial` can only be used on fpgas to set initial values,  it can not change over time  with in this block, it could be updated in a separate block. NB: this is the only time when two blocks can set the same reg.

`#delay` values are ignored by synthesis. arbitrary asynchronous timing control can not be implemented reliably and so is not part of the synthesis tools.

To develop Verilog counters a clock is normally used, this meant he counter value will be held in a flip-flop. For the count to be observable you will need a clock slow enough.

The following counter will overflow and keep counting continuously

```
module counter_s2( 
  input            clk,
  output reg [7:0] count
);

initial begin
  count= 'b0;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
 count <= count + 1 ;
end

endmodule
```

If it is for **ASIC** then you should be using resets instead of relying on initial.

```
module counter_s2( 
  input            clk,
  input            rst_n, //Active Low reset
  output reg [7:0] count
);

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    count <= 'b0;
  end
  else begin
    count <= count + 1 ;
  end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: I tried to run this code but I am not getting any output on LEDs. LEDs are Off. And kindly tell me that how input clk is coming to this counter? Is it coming automatically from board clock or do we have to configure it ourselves to give it to our program. I am making my concepts clear because I am new to Verilog.
Thanks!

Comment: It will not do anything with out a clock. The clock is one of the most fundamental things about digital electronics, it will vary from FPGA to FPGA. For the [Xilinx Spartan6](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug382.pdf) if your still having trouble I would ask about clock setup over on [Electronics SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).